# List in python does not show index

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
Dueno = [28957346, 'Juan', 'Perez', 4789689, 'Belgrano 101']
dni = 26000000
print('Su dni es: ')
input()
for elementos in Dueno:
    if dni > 26000000:
        print(Dueno[3])
    else:
        break
```

I'm trying to show the owner's phone if the ID is greater than 26000000 / but I can't find that, help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your `dni` variable is not greater than 26000000, so the condition won't pass.
2. You don't need a for loop here, like at all, its code does nothing with the loop itself.

Comment: How would you pose them?

Comment: just remove for loop completely and leave only `if` and `print` lines, also, set yout `dni` to something like 26000001 or change the condition to `if dni >= 26000000` so it will accept 26000000, too.

Comment: Thank you very much, I thought a loop was more appropriate, but you've hit the right one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you will have multiple owners (Dueno) and you want to grab the fourth number in the list (which is their phone number) if their ID (the first number in the list) is greater than 26000000.

So for that, you would want to use a for loop:

```
Duenos = [[28957346, 'Juan', 'Perez', 4789689, 'Belgrano 101'], 
         [14952151, 'Pedro', 'Lopez', 5214649, 'Belgrano 102'],
         [31152151, 'Carlos', 'Garcia', 1214589, 'Belgrano 103'],]
dni = 26000000

numeros = []
for Dueno in Duenos:
    if Dueno[0] > dni:
        numeros.append(Dueno[3])
print(numeros)

[4789689, 1214589] # Output
```

Or you could use list comprehension:

```
numeros = [Dueno[3] for Dueno in Duenos if Dueno[0] > dni]
print(numeros)
[4789689, 1214589] # Output
```

Comment: There are two more ways than I had thought, I think I will have them as the first option to edit the code.